# SNMP Programming -single API Thread self-

Tags: snmp

I'm facing problem to use NET_SNMP **single API Thread self**; so i used this link http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/README.thread.html to resolve my problem successfully to get the value of an OID from the MIB, but i dont know if there is **predefined function** to **increment this value automatically** ?

any help would be greatly appreciated.